# Can mass loss via accretion occur on stellar remnants?

Tags: star, black-hole, neutron-star, white-dwarf, accretion

We know that normal stars can lose mass to a binary companion. But can this happen to neutron stars and white dwarfs? Let's say a stellar black hole is being orbited by a white dwarf or neutron star. How close would they have to orbit each other for mass loss to occur, if it is possible?